# Reload points on Google Maps dynamically

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps

I´m using a jquery plugin (*Gmap*) to load a google map , and several markers on it.

I need to refresh the markers(*like changing a category or something from a drop down menu*) and charge some other points on the same map without reloading the whole thing (*only the markers*)

How can i do this?, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array of marker arrays, if you know what I'm talking about. Iterate over each marker, and use the `setMap()` method to remove it from/place it on the map.

```
var active = 0,
    map = *map*,
    markers = [
      [*marker1*, *marker2*],
      [*marker3*, *marker4*],
    ];

function setActive( m, map ){

  // remove active markers
  for( var i=0; i<markers[active].length; i++){
    markers[active][i].setMap(null);
  }

  // place new markers
  for( var i=0; i<markers[active].length; i++){
    markers[m][i].setMap(map);
  }

  active = m;
}

// Show the second row of markers:
setActive( 1, map );
```